# Remote Client is unable to connect to TCP Server on VPS (Getting 10060 error)

Tags: vps, tcp, ping, timeout, netstat

I have searched all over the internet for the solution. Unfortunately, I could not get any working solution yet. Here is the story.

I am running TCP server for small communication application on the VPS with Window Server 2012. VPS is the commercial one with some monthly fee.

Say I am using 10000 port to listen on my server. On my server, I have allowed both inbound and outbound firewall rule for tcp port 10000 for private, public and domain level. When I perform  "netstat -a" using command prompt on my vps, I can see that the port is opened and listening from any where. This is the display from netstat:

Proto  Local Address         State
TCP    0.0.0.0:10000         Listening

However, when I run the tcp client from remote computer, I always get 10060 error saying that "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond".

So I checked if the IP address was correct using ping command on my remote client computer. This is the display from ping:

Ping statistics for xx.xx.xx.xx:
 Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
 Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
 Minimum = 188ms, Maximum = 213ms, Average = 195ms

The ip address of vps server I pinged responsed perfectly with valid statisics. Everything seemed ok except the remote tcp client can not get connected to the tcp server on the vps.

I even tried while both firewall switched off on the vps and the remote client computer. But I still get the same response 100060 with error.

It is really frustrating. I can not think of what else can disturb the connection between server and client here.

For your informaiton, I tested the connection on another vps from other company, the connection was perfect between the tcp server and the remote client. The server and client application are built on Dot Net Frame work version 4.0. It seems this application is not working on some vps and working on some other vps.

Your idea will be really appreciated.

Kindest regards.

Comment: Do you have another firewall? Maybe provided bhy the VPS provider?

Comment: I do not know about that. If vps provider provide another firewall on top of window firewall, how can i control that ?

Comment: IF that is the case, they will provide access to it in their control panels when you log in to their service to manage your VPS.

Comment: I will check and come back with answer.